# .Net 8 MVC: Best way to fill a DropDownList with data from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

My app works with tests, and I have a view where a user can edit a test, and for that I have DropDownList test selector on top as the next:

```
@using TestMeAdmin.Models
@model TestMeAdmin.Models.TestViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tests, Model.Tests, "-- Select Test --", new { name = "ddlTests", id = "ddlTests" })
```

Which fetchs its data from controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Tests()
{

    var tests = await _repo.GetTestsAsync(filter: "");

    var viewModel = new TestViewModel()
    {
        TestId = "",
        Tests = new List<SelectListItem>()
    };

    foreach (var test in tests)
    {
        viewModel.Tests.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = test.TestId, Text = test.Test });
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And everything's working fine, but I'm sure -regarding the controller part- that there should be a cleaner way of doing this.

Is there any better/shorter way than creating a `List<SelectListItem>` and looping over the list of tests?

I'm not using Razor for anything in special, is there could be a better way for this without Razor I'm also open to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct but how about to replace Tests value for this:

```
Tests = tests.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.TestId, Text = x.Test}).ToList()
```

Use linq in Select method, don't need to use foreach loop

Comment: I like it, thanks @BlackSD.

Answer (score 1):

-> You can use the LINQ 'Select' method in code. please Convert the
IEnumerable into List

-> Please refer updated code:-

-> Controller:-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Tests()
{

var tests = await _repo.GetTestsAsync(filter: "");

var viewModel = new TestViewModel
{
    TestId = "",
    Tests = tests.Select(t => new SelectListItem { Value = t.TestId, Text = t.Test }).ToList()
};

return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input @Heny Patel. The same comment has already made BlackSD, and I've already accepted the answer.